# Is there a way to query mysql for all records that are not in a set, even when its empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I know mysql says:

> In general, tables containing NULL values and empty tables are “edge cases.” When writing subqueries, always consider whether you have taken those two possibilities into account.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html

But this doesn't make sense.  If I say:

`select * from users where users.id NOT IN (NULL)`;

shouldn't it return all users?  Even by their own logic which says:

> NOT IN is an alias for <> ALL. Thus, these two statements are the same:

which to me says, return all records where id does not equal NULL, which is all records.

So the question is, **how can I achieve selecting all records that are not in a particular set, even if that set is empty**.

Obviously, in my application code(a Rails app), I can check if the set is empty and modify my query, but that seems ridiculous.  Is there any way to do this all in sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the common mistake of assuming that `NULL` is or has a value - in this case you are assuming that `NULL = empty set`.

`NULL` means undefined - so in all RDMS `NULL = NULL` is `NULL` and `NULL <> NULL` is also `NULL`. For that matter `Anything = NULL` is `NULL` as is `Anything <> NULL`. `NULL` in a RDMS is the same as division by zero in mathematics.

This is why you have to use the special comparison operator `IS NULL` rather than `=`.

The query as you have structured it therefore translates to `select * from users where users.id NOT IN (`*undefined*`)`. And `users.id NOT IN (`*undefined*`)` is itself *undefined*.

I assume the `NULL` in your query is from a variable in Rails - I'll call it pnl (possibly null list). So this query will give you what you want.

```
select * from users where users.id NOT IN (pnl) OR pnl IS NULL;
```

Comment: great answer! thanks for explaining! for me the simpler workaround is to just join the empty array into a comma-separated string